# Android crashes after update unless I put another memory card

Tags: external-sd, crashes, htc-desire-hd

I have HTC Desire HD and installed an official update of the system: Android 2.3.5, HTC Sense 3.0, system 3.12.405.1.

After the update my phone runs very slowly and reboots every 2 minutes. If I remove the memory card it runs well. If I change the memory card to another empty one then everything is also good.

But I have a lot of apps and other data on that card and I don't want to format it.

I looked at a log, there are a lot of mistakes like this:

`W/ResourceType(13907): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0200df (t=1 e=223) in package 0 (error -2147483647)`

Link to the beginning of the log (250kb):

http://pastebin.com/P3zq0k5x

Full log (3.3Mb, phone rebooted several times while writting this log) is here:

http://file.karelia.ru/9kjwqz/

I don't understand anything in programming or Android. Can you help me? Maybe I should just remove one of the apps and problem would be solved?

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and resolved it easily enough by carefully reading the short messages that were regularly popping up on my screen informing me just what apps were causing my phone to "force close." In my case the culprit was the Volume+ app. As soon as I uninstalled Volume+ the phone was right as rain.

Comment: Unfourtunately I didn't get any messages on my screen...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear your hassles however it is actually good news that your phone works well without the problem sd card. Since your phone runs like crap and reboots you may be forced to use a computer sd card reader to salvage what you can.

I hope someone can make sense of those log files, otherwise maybe mounting your sd card on a desktop pc and running scandisk for errors (depending on your platform). But I would backup all the data I could from it as soon as I could to your computer hd.

This is one of those times we hate computers and they remind us to back everything up 3 or four times ;) You can use apps like http://www.appbrain.com/ to make an online version of your apps. As for your data you could sync with a dropbox app or some other kind of sync app I use sftp on my linux desktop or cygwin ssh on windows with https://market.android.com/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite&feature=search_result

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

may be some apps is running from your SD card.

instead of internal memory. some of your application is stored in your memory card that's the reason.

apps like:

```
/mnt/asec/com.threebanana.notes-1/pkg.apk
/mnt/asec/com.mobillness.shakytower.full-1/pkg.apk
/mnt/asec/kr.sira.measure-2/pkg.apk
/mnt/asec/com.droidhen.irunner-1/pkg.apk
```

.
.
.

Comment: I understand it. But what apps?

Comment: check this edited ans...

Comment: I've deleted all these 4 apps, but the problem is still here :(

Comment: I mentioned .... not only this 4 there are many under this "/asec/" folder, delete this folder once and check  it. if problem exist send once again the error log files.

Comment: I haven't micro SD adapter to put it on card reader unf. So I can't remove that folder to HD to recover it later. I can only delete all those apps that are installed to the card. But as I said in my first post, I don't want to lose all apps installed to the card, their settings and their data. Is there another way to determine tjose apps that causes the problem?

Comment: I found micro SD adapter and removed folder .android _secure from memory card to HD. After that the problem disappeared. But now I can't use my apps that were installed to the card. What now?