# Should I do the factory reset? If yes, what will I lose?

Tags: external-sd, factory-reset, reboot, htc-desire-s

My HTC Desire S is working fine when I don't put my micro SD card in it (this card was free with the phone). But the phone keeps restarting every few minutes if I keep the memory card in it. By that, I could say that the phone is fine, but the issue can be either with the memory card or the phone not supporting memory card anymore. The phone and memory card worked completely fine for 8 months.

The thing is, if the same memory card is inserted in any other mobile, be it an Android or any other smartphone, that phone will not restart and the data is completely readable too. So, the memory card is fine. When I insert some other memory card on my phone, then my phone does not restart too. So that means the issue is with *my phone & that particular memory card* combo.

I am ready to uninstall each and every app from my phone, but will that solve my problem? Should I perform the factory reset? Will it solve my issue? What will I lose if will do the factory reset? Like: contacts, SMS, call logs, APN settings, etc. Any free software to backup all these?

But maybe I am going in the wrong direction. Maybe there is some easy way to get the phone and memory card working.

Comment: have you read **[Android crashes after update unless I put another memory card](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17550/android-crashes-after-update-unless-i-put-another-memory-card)** ?

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12802/factory-reset-to-restore-performance-what-are-the-disadvantages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing a factory reset *will not* modify the SD card in any way. Only the data on the phone will be deleted. Contacts that are set up to sync with your Google account will restore, but everything else will be gone.

If you have applications installed on the SD card, I would start there. Uninstall them, or move them back to the device storage. You say that it only crashes when it is in your phone, and not any other Android phone. This would make me think there is probably an app installed on the SD card for your phone. You also said that it doesn't reboot when a different card is in your phone, again leading me to believe that there could be an app that is installed to the SD card that is causing problems.

If you think there is something in your data that is causing the issue, then backing up the data with Titanium Backup will just restore any "issue" that there is.

If you think the problem is with the data on the SD card, then you can format it under storage in settings.

I would also consider the SD card itself could have issues. The SD cards that come with the devices are very cheap cards and usually one of the slower class type of SD card. I have had a few of them last only a couple of months before. I suggest getting a better SD card, one that is at least a class 6. If you have a slower class card, this could also potentially cause issues with some applications.

Comment: mine is class 4.

Comment: Only the data on the phone will be deleted.  - all data?

Comment: no, not "all data". It will not remove anything on the internal sdcard, nor the external sdcard. But any settings and things that applications save in /data/data will be gone.

Answer (score 2):

First, to answer one question simply, yes you will lose all of your data by doing a factory reset unless you back it up.

If you feel a factory reset is necessary, I would use a program like Titanium Backup to backup your data. This is if you are rooted.

As for the issue with your SD card, it could be a number of things. You said that it worked fine for 8 months - is there an app you installed recently that may be the cause of the problem? Something that didn't run properly when you first opened it? Or an app that has issues while running.

Comment: +1 for "softwae installed 8 motnths ago". maybe you can find a candidate that causes the reboot with a desktop pc an look what file were created/modified 8 months ago on the sd card.

Answer (score 1):

According to your explanation:

- The memory card works fine on other devices
- Your phone reads other memory cards just fine
- It's when they work together that it fails

You installed an app on your phone. This app was moved to the memory card either by you or another 3rd-party software, and this app is having memory consumption issues.

1. Go into the card and check all those "weird" folders like `com.android.mapguide` and the like and make a list of them
2. Remove the card and go to Manage Applications

   1. Make a note of the application on the list
   2. Uninstall the applications on the list
   3. Move the folders and files on the list to another media
3. Insert your card, the device *should* work
4. One-by-one reinstall the apps one at a time, writing down what you did and restarting the phone between installs

The data on one of the files/folders were creating the bug, but because you removed the files and folders from your phone.

Answer (score 0):

You could always format your SD card.

If your phone is rooted, it might have an attachment to your SD card that's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do a factory reset and lose some data, it may be more important to find out why your phone resets and fix this.

You can try to attach a debug-logger to the phone and watch in the debug log what happens before the restart. If you are lucky, the debug log contains a hint of what caused the reboot. If you donot know what "attach a debug-logger" means ask some android software-developper in you neighborhood for help.

I think there is one file on the SD card (or an error in the filesystem of the card) that causes the reboot. Maybe the media scanner crashes because of an invalid MP3 or video file.