# Is it safe to Factory Reset my tablet to improve performance? Will I lose the uninstallable apps?

Tags: internal-storage, factory-reset

I'm going to reset my Android tab because its internal memory is low.

Is it safe to erase the system data of my android tablet (not rooted)? If I restore the factory setting of my Android, will the uninstallable apps be also removed or only those that can be uninstalled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it safe to erase the system data of my android tablet (not rooted)?

Yes, it's safe to Factory Reset your tablet.

> If I restore the factory setting of my Android, will the uninstallable
>   apps be also removed or only those that can be uninstalled?

Only those that can be uninstalled will be removed. Doing a Factory Reset is like making your phone brand new. You will lose all your installed apps and all your data, but you will still have the stock / default apps that your phone came with.

Once the phone reboots after a Factory Reset, you start from scratch. You will log-in to your Google account, and have the option of restoring the apps you installed and bought before from Google Play.

**Related questions:**

- [Factory reset to restore performance? What are the disadvantages?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12802/factory-reset-to-restore-performance-what-are-the-disadvantages)
- [Should i do the factory reset? If yes, what will i lose?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18029/should-i-do-the-factory-reset-if-yes-what-will-i-lose)
- [Will factory resetting my device remove the Android upgrade?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12626/will-factory-resetting-my-device-remove-the-android-upgrade)

Answer (score 1):

Your phone will be as good as the day you brought it. Factory resetting your phone only cleans up the apps you installed yourself and not the preinstalled applications. A factory reset really only deals with the Data and the Cache partitions and does not mess with the system.