# Google contacts

Tags: contacts, factory-reset, hardware, google, delete

I'm using an android phone (Samsung core prime) and all of my contacts numbers saved in 'google contacts'. There are no contacts in my 'phone storage' or 'sim card'. Now, my question is, if I reset my phone, what will happen with my contacts? Will it delete from google contacts or no? Please answer me

Comment: Please try searching for your problem on this site or others, e.g. Google, before asking a new question. As it happens, we specifically have a number of questions with this. Finding them is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR

If you sign in to the device after the reset with the Google account which had been used for the backup (the primary Google account usually), the contacts which had been backed up will get restored.

#### Longer version with source:

I'll keep this short and to the point, as most of it has already been discussed [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/18038/92056) in @[RyanConrad](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/1951/ryan-conrad)'s answer, a relevant part of which I shall reproduce here:

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

> Doing a factory reset WILL NOT modify the sdcard in any way. Only the data on the phone will be deleted. **Contacts that are set up to sync with your Google account will restore**, but everything else will be gone.